In Janus Graph db how to get notified about new vertex/edges?
In Janus graph db, is there a way to get notified when a new vertex/edge is added/removed/updated?
One solution is this https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/transaction-log/#log-configuration
But one limitation I can see is that logIdentifier is required, can we do it without that?
